# Glass fuse - Selection rule

Tags: fuses

If I have a circuit which have current consumption 100mA, what is the value of the fuse that I have to select so to open (burn) the fuse in the case of a short circuit? There is a theoretical or practical rule?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fuse's hold current should be 100mA + some tolerance, which really depends on your application. Do you have inrush currents? Do you have inductive loads? There is also the fuse's voltage rating (12Vdc fuse is different from 220Vac fuse) and the fuse speed (Slow blow, standard, fast blow).

Comment: I don't have inductive loads and my supply is 12Volt.  There is a rule about the selection of volts and current of the fuse with resistors load and inductive loads respectively?

Comment: Your application dictates your choices. Why did you choose 100mA and not 1A? What sort of abuse can your components withstand?